# fread and fwrite result file size are different

Tags: c, fwrite, fread, filesize

I am writing a program in Visual Studio.
I copied a file using `fread` and `fwrite`.
The output file size is bigger then input file.
Can you explain the reason?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    int fsize;

    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    FILE *ofp = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);

    buffer = (char *)malloc(fsize);
    memset(buffer, 0, fsize); // buffer를 0으로 초기화

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, fsize, 1, fp);

    fwrite(buffer, fsize, 1, ofp);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ofp);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Open the files in binary mode.

Comment: It might be better to `#include <sys/stat.h>` and then do `struct stat buffer = {};` `stat("test.txt", &buffer);` and then `size_t fsize = buffer.st_size;` to get the size of the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You open the files in text mode, which on the Windows operating system using Visual Studio involves non trivial translation phases, including end of line conversion. If your files have binary contents, such as executable, image and document files, end of line conversion replaces '\n' bytes with CR LF pairs, thereby increasing the output size.

You can avoid this issue by opening the files in binary mode with `"rb"` and `"wb"` mode strings.

Also note that a stream must be open in binary mode for `ftell()` to reliably return the file size, assuming the file supports seeking and is not larger than `LONG_MAX` which is only 2GB on Windows. Using `stat` to retrieve the file size from the OS is a better approach for POSIX systems. Copying the file one block at a time is also more reliable: it works for streams that do not support seeking and allows for copying files larger than available memory.

Here is a modified version with error checking:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char *inputfile = "test.txt";
    const char *outputfile = "out.txt";

    FILE *fp = fopen(inputfile, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", inputfile, strerror(errno);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *ofp = fopen(outputfile, "wb");
    if (ofp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", outputfile, strerror(errno);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot seek to the end of file: %s\n",
                inputfile, strerror(errno);
        return 1;
    }
   
    size_t fsize = ftell(fp);

    char *buffer = calloc(fsize, 1);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate %zu bytes: %s\n",
                fsize, strerror(errno);
        return 1;
    }

    rewind(fp);
    size_t nread = fread(buffer, fsize, 1, fp);
    if (nread != fsize) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: read %zu bytes, file size is %zu bytes\n".
                inputfile, nread, fsize);
    }

    size_t nwritten = fwrite(buffer, nread, 1, ofp);
    if (nwritten != nread) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: wrote %zu bytes, write size is %zu bytes\n".
                outputfile, nwritten, nread);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (fclose(ofp)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error closing file: %s\n".
                outputfile, strerror(errno));
    }
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. The difference between input and output files is the exact number of new lines of input file.

Comment: @Byung-ikKang: that's a coincidence, because some or all of the CR bytes in the input file may be stripped and some other conversions can happen depending on the locale settings (code page, etc.) You must use binary mode.

Comment: Oh really? It's a coincidence? haha

Comment: @Byung-ikKang: if the difference in size is exactly the number of newlines, a possible explanation is the input file is a text file coming from a unix system, where there are no CR bytes and where all newlines get translated to CR LF pairs.